# Draw RR data chart with java

Tags: java, charts, rrd4j

I'm storing some data and I want to use it to plot a round-robin chart on a web page and I thought that RRDB4J could be a good fit. Unfortunately it’s not much documented, so I’m asking for advice.

I was thinking to use RRD4J+mongoDB for storing the data in round robin fashion, then query and show the data with Chart.js and https://github.com/adessoAG/wicked-charts and apache wicket.

Suggestions? Tutorials?